# Intellij idea create custom language plugin extending javascript

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to create a language plugin for intellij idea, for sweet js.

Is there any way i can get the syntax highlighting and other javascript language support for my project from existing javascript language support in intellij idea?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this would be possible. The JavaScript plugin works with a syntax tree that has a certain structure, and sweet.js allows to change the structure in all sorts of ways that the plugin will not be able to work with.

Also, the plugin is not open-source and does not expose any documented APIs, so it's very challenging to build something on top of it even for the tasks which do fit well with the plugin's design.